# How to check if a string can be converted to int, and if so, add it to the list

Tags: python

For example, I have a list:

```
l = ["z","u","k","h","r","a","1","2","3"]
```

How can I check if an element in the list can be int, and if so, convert it to int and replace the str in the list, so that my list would look like

```
l = ["z","u","k","h","r","a",1,2,3]
```

Comment: please make an attempt before asking and if you run into a problem provide a [mcve] in your question

Comment: You convert them and handle the exception if it doesn't work.

Comment: Was adding an answer using list comprehension, but too late... `[x if not x.isnumeric(x) else int(x) for x in l]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write yourself a simple function that tries to convert a value to an integer.

```
>>> def try_int(x):
...     try:
...         return int(x)
...     except ValueError:
...         return x
... 
>>> l = ["z","u","k","h","r","a","1","2","3"]
>>> [try_int(x) for x in l]
['z', 'u', 'k', 'h', 'r', 'a', 1, 2, 3]
```

Following the [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) principle, we just try to convert the value `x`. That's easier than coding complicated checks in order to find out whether it could be converted.

Comment: That's the way I would have done it. One could also use an often ignored method and simply write: 
`[int(x) if x.isdecimal() else x for x in l]`.

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt that won't work because `'-1'.isdecimal()` -> `False`.

Comment: Yes, `isdecimal()` works only, if you know that the list elements are strings and that the integer values are non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `try-except` block around the conversion and ignore the `ValueError` exceptions:

```
for i, n in enumerate(l):
    try:
        l[i] = int(n)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```